# Do not show link of current page and change to different link instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

If I'm on my `/log_in` page, how would I to make it show the `sign_up` link and vice versa?

```
<% if /sign_up do %>
   <%= link_to "Sign up", sign_up_path %>
<% else %>
   <%= link_to "Login", log_in_path %>
<% end %>
```

Lets say the routes mapped to:

```
get "/sign_up" => "devise/registrations#new"
get "/log_in" => "devise/sessions#new"
```

Since I am using Devise. How would this be with the Devise routes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your routes with `as:` so that you can use `sign_up_path` and `log_in_path`:

```
get "sign_up" => "devise/registrations#new", as: "sign_up"
get "log_in" => "devise/sessions#new", as: "log_in"
```

I assume you've run `rails g devise:views` so that you have

- Login view `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`
- Signup view `app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`

Why not just hand code the links instead of using an if statement?

```
# signup view
<%= link_to "Log In", log_in_path %>

# login view
<%= link_to "Sign Up", sign_up_path %>
```

But if you really do want to use an if statement, you can use `current_page?(named_path)` to check. For example:

```
<% current_page?(log_in_path) ? link_to("Sign Up", sign_up_path) : link_to("Log In", log_in_path) %>
```